# map() returns undefined error after Mongoose populate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```
const form = await Form.findOne({ _id: res._id }).populate({
   path: "activity.viewedBy",
   model: User,
});

const a = await form.activity.map((a) => a.viewedBy);

console.log(a.map((e) => e.email));
```

"Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"

Why?
`a` is an array, full of objects, like this:

```
[
   {
      id: 123,
      email: example@email.com
   },
   {
      id: 456,
      email: nice@email.com
   }
]
```

**Edit, sharing the whole async function:**

```
const viewForm = async (req, res) => {
    const form = await Form.findOne({ _id: res._id }).populate({
       path: "activity.viewedBy",
       model: User,
    });
    
    const a = await form.activity.map((a) => a.viewedBy);
    
    console.log(a.map((e) => e.email));

    await Form.updateOne(
        { _id: res._id },
        {
            $push: {
                activity: {
                    viewedBy: res.user,
                    date: new Date(),
                },
            },
        }
    );

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(`Form viewed.`),
    };
};
```

**Edit2:**

There was an `undefined` in the array, among the objects, I didn't notice that... That's why I was getting the undefined.

Comment: can you share the complete async function ?

Comment: @brk shared it.

Answer (score 1):

`a` probably has a different structure than you think (try `console.log(a)`), just proving:

```js
const data = [
   {
      id: 123,
      email: "example@email.com"
   },
   {
      id: 456,
      email: "nice@email.com"
   }
];

const result = data.map((a) => a.email);

console.log(result);
```

Also, giving your variables meaningful names can help to prevent mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
await form.activity.map((a) => a.viewedBy);
```

will return an array of `viewedBy` values. So the array `a` doesn't contain the full objects. Instead, it contains an array of `viewedBy` elements.
Also, please take a look at the functionality of the `map()` function.